# "Zipping" two dataframes by column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

all

Suppose I have a dataframe like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": range(6), "key": [0,1]*3})
df1

    A   key
0   0   0
1   1   1
2   2   0
3   3   1
4   4   0
5   5   1
```

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"C": ["k0-"+str(x) for x in range(3)] + ["k1-"+str(x) for x in range(3)] , "key": [0]*3 + [1]*3})   k0-1
df2

    C   key
0   k0-0    0
1   k0-1    0
2   k0-2    0
3   k1-0    1
4   k1-1    1
5   k1-2    1
```

Values in C are all unique and values in `key` have no such pattern in a real dataset.

I'm trying to merge the two with a resulting dataframe, where values in column C will be taken exactly once for a matching value in column `key`.

I.e.

```
    A   key C
0   0   0   k0-0 
1   1   1   k1-0
2   2   0   k0-1
3   3   1   k1-1
4   4   0   k0-2
5   5   1   k1-2
```

The order doesn't matter, i.e. values in C do not need to be taken sequentially. This is a toy example, I have ~10 keys in reality.

I know I can probably do an outer join and then somehow drop the non-unique C values. But this could be an overkill, as there are too many rows in the real datasets (~30k).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I wrong or does your desired output not match your input?  I see `'k1-3'` in the output and I don't see `'k1-3'` in `df2`.

Comment: Sorry, inadvertently shifted the sequence, now fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra column to be used in the join:

```
df1['order'] = df1.groupby('key').cumcount()
df2['order'] = df2.groupby('key').cumcount()

# If you want to match on random order:
# df2['order'] = df2.sample(frac=1).groupby('key').cumcount()

df1.merge(df2, on=['key', 'order'])
```

Result:

```
   A  key  order     C
0  0    0      0  k0-0
1  1    1      0  k1-0
2  2    0      1  k0-1
3  3    1      1  k1-1
4  4    0      2  k0-2
5  5    1      2  k1-2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build a dictionary of iterators and call `next` on the appropriate iterator depending on the `'key'`.

```
g = {k: iter(v) for k, v in df2.groupby('key').C}
df1.assign(C=[next(g[x]) for x in df1.key])

   A  key     C
0  0    0  k0-0
1  1    1  k1-0
2  2    0  k0-1
3  3    1  k1-1
4  4    0  k0-2
5  5    1  k1-2
```